# ESC key trapping in Google Sheets script

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Pressing ESC after running this -

```
function Test1() {
  var LOCresponse = Browser.msgBox("aaa", "bbb", Browser.Buttons.OK_CANCEL)
}
```

gives this -
"Error resuming script execution".
Is there a way to trap the ESC key to make it do something different while displaying a
prompt for response in Google Scripts?

I was hoping it would return a response I can access and use.

Comment: Try push the cancel button instead

Comment: @Cooper Wise counsel, indeed. And entirely unavoidable. Sadly the App Script [issue tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/317894979?pli=1) records this as a known but unresolved issue.

Comment: Maybe the buttonSet enum could provide another option  OK_Cancel_Esc - [Buttons.ButtonSet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/button-set).  There seem to have been a  lot of new commands added since I've been here that I could have easily lived without but I could see how this might be useful but I could easily live without it.

Comment: Copilot shows 3 options 
1 of 3 Using Google Apps Script Triggers:
o Instead of listening for key events directly, you can set up a trigger that runs a function periodically or based on specific events (e.g., when the sheet is edited).
o For example, you can create an onEdit trigger that checks if the ESC key was pressed after an edit operation.
o Here’s a simplified example:
JavaScript
function onEdit(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Escape') {
        // Your logic for handling the Escape key press goes here
        Logger.log('Escape key pressed');
    }
}

Comment: 2. 2 of 3 Custom Dialogs or Sidebar:
o If you want to capture the ESC key press during a custom dialog or sidebar interaction, you can create a custom UI using Google Apps Script.
o For example, when displaying a custom dialog, you can add buttons (including a “Cancel” button) and handle the button clicks accordingly.
o The ESC key press can be treated as a cancellation action within your custom UI.

Comment: 3. 3 of 3Web App with HTML and JavaScript:
o If you need more advanced interactions, consider creating a Google Apps Script web app.
o You can use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript to build a custom interface that listens for key events, including the ESC key.
o The web app can be embedded in a sidebar or opened separately.

Comment: Option 1 - 1 . On Edit - does nothing. No surprise, since I want ESC trapped while running a script and onEdit is active when I am editing a cell. Option 2. I think this is the buttonset you mentioned.  I son;t see an ESC option. Is there a way to add the ESC trap?  Option 3, I'm not competent to do the HTML version. I would be happy to try an example if one is available.